# How to stop JavaScript in Web Worker from the outside?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am calling a JavaScript function through a `onclick` event from my webpage, which on event will start running synchronously in my `Worker`. I want to know if there is any way to stop that JS function after getting the desired result through `onclick` event i.e manually from my webpage.

Comment: Isn't there a `.terminate()` function for this already?

Comment: @Batu.Khan Yes but unfortunately it not only stops the current code execution but *also* kills the whole worker thus requiring a whole new copy to be created if you want to process more data

Answer (score 3):

> So I wanted to know if there is any way to stop that js function after getting the desired result...

If you have the desired result, the web worker shouldn't still be running. It should terminate (or go dormant) after sending the result to the main page. It might still have a `message` handler registered (so you can tell it to do something again), but it shouldn't still be *running*.

> How to stop Javascript in webworker from outside?

If the web worker is continuously running code such as a tight loop that never yields back to the browser, you can terminate it via the [`terminate` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dom-worker-terminate) on the `Worker` instance:

Where you start the worker:

```
var worker = new Worker("yourscript.js");
```

Later, when you want to kill it:

```
worker.terminate();
```

If the worker yields back to the browser periodically (via `setTimeout`, or just because it's waiting for a `message` with the next thing to work on), you can post it an application-specific message telling it to clean up and terminate.